# How can i use UserSettings when i import wpf usercontrols/views via mef

Tags: wpf, mef, settings

i have the following scenario. i have a main application wich can import usercontrols/views from other .dlls via mef. all works fine. but if i define usersettings im my plugin dlls, i got the following error

Das Konfigurationssystem konnte nicht initialisiert werden.

is there any way to include the settings in my plugin.dlls? or are there other ways to use UserSettings with plugin.dlls and mef?

thx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First i'm sorry, i really dont know what i did wrong in my first try with usersettings.

all i can say now its works like a charme.

i built usersettings for my plugin project with vs2010 and use it in xaml like this:

```
 <Slider x:Name="zoomer" Width="100" 
 Value="{Binding Source={x:Static Properties:Settings.Default}, Path=Zoomer, Mode=TwoWay}" 
 Minimum="1.0" Maximum="2.0" TickFrequency="0.1" IsSnapToTickEnabled="True">
```

in my plugin project i take the Application.Current.Exit += ApplicationExit; to call

```
Settings.Default.Save();
```

Answer (score 0):

I think in UserSettings are defined on an application, so they don't really work with libraries.  One way to handle plugin settings is to have a settings service which the host exports, and have your plugins import the service and use it to save/load their settings.

Comment: where would you save/load this settings then? isolatedstorage?

Comment: @blindmeis IsolatedStorage or whatever other mechanism the host can use to save settings.